# how to merge multiple json files with same structure into one json file with same structure (combined all into one with keeping same structure))

Tags: json, jq

I need to merge file1.json file2.json (could be more) into onefile.json.

version is always the same value in all files. however vulnerabilities array and dependency_files array values different but there might be duplicate/which I want to remove if any after the merge

file1.json:

```
{
    "version": "x.x.x",
    "vulnerabilities": [
        {
            "id": "0000"
        },
        {
            "id": "11111"
        },
        {
            "id": "2222"
        }
    ],
    "dependency_files": [
        {
            "name": "name0000"
        },
        {
            "name": "name1111"
        },
        {
            "name": "name2222"
        }
        
    ]
}
```

file2.json:

```
{
    "version": "x.x.x",
    "vulnerabilities": [

        {
            "id": "2222"
        },
        {
            "id": "3333"
        }
    ],
    "dependency_files": [
        {
            "name": "name2222"
        },
        {
            "name": "name3333"
        }
    ]
}
```

onefile.json:

```
{
    "version": "x.x.x",
    "vulnerabilities": [
        {
            "id": "0000"
        },
        {
            "id": "11111"
        },
        {
            "id": "2222"
        },
        {
            "id": "3333"
        }
    ],
    "dependency_files": [
        {
            "name": "name0000"
        },
        {
            "name": "name1111"
        },
        {
            "name": "name2222"
        },
        {
            "name": "name3333"
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried a lot with no luck

Answer (score 1):

Using this python code

```py
import json

def merge_dicts(*dicts):
    r = {}
    skip = 'version'
    for item in dicts:
        for key, value in item.items():
            if (key == skip):
                r[skip] = value
            else:
                r.setdefault(key, []).extend(value)
                unique = []
                for obj in r[key]:
                    if obj not in unique:
                        unique.append(obj)
                r[key] = unique
    return r

with open("file1.json") as file_1:
    data_1 = json.load(file_1)
with open("file2.json") as file_2:
    data_2 = json.load(file_2)

with open('data.json', 'w') as merge_file:
    json.dump(merge_dicts(data_1, data_2), merge_file, indent = 4)
```

Result

```json
{
    "version": "x.x.x",
    "vulnerabilities": [
        {
            "id": "0000"
        },
        {
            "id": "11111"
        },
        {
            "id": "2222"
        },
        {
            "id": "3333"
        }
    ],
    "dependency_files": [
        {
            "name": "name0000"
        },
        {
            "name": "name1111"
        },
        {
            "name": "name2222"
        },
        {
            "name": "name3333"
        }
    ]
}
```

This code is multiple json files support

```
import os, json

def merge_dicts(*dicts):
    r = {}
    skip = 'version'
    for item in dicts:
        for key, value in item.items():
            if (key == skip):
                r[skip] = value
            else:
                r.setdefault(key, []).extend(value)
                unique = []
                for obj in r[key]:
                    if obj not in unique:
                        unique.append(obj)
                r[key] = unique
    return r

json_files = [pos_json for pos_json in os.listdir('./') if pos_json.endswith('.json')]
a = []
print(type(a))
for json_file in json_files:
    with open(json_file) as file_item:
        read_data = json.load(file_item)
        a.append(read_data)
        file_item.close()

with open('data.json', 'w') as merge_file:
    json.dump(merge_dicts(*tuple(a)), merge_file, indent = 4)
```

Comment: @EklasAldwairi, No problem don't forget your vote me, encourage me.

Comment: how can I update that python script if I don't know how many number of files? let's assume all .json files in current dir. possible?

Comment: @EklasAldwairi, added code for multiple JSON files.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a `reduce` on all files, initialized with the first, hence no need for the `-n` option:

```bash
jq '
  reduce inputs as {$vulnerabilities, $dependency_files} (.;
    .vulnerabilities = (.vulnerabilities + $vulnerabilities | unique_by(.id))
    | .dependency_files = (.dependency_files + $dependency_files | unique_by(.name))
  )
' file*.json
```

```json
{
  "version": "x.x.x",
  "vulnerabilities": [
    {
      "id": "0000"
    },
    {
      "id": "11111"
    },
    {
      "id": "2222"
    },
    {
      "id": "3333"
    }
  ],
  "dependency_files": [
    {
      "name": "name0000"
    },
    {
      "name": "name1111"
    },
    {
      "name": "name2222"
    },
    {
      "name": "name3333"
    }
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/pgspBDCY_kj)

Comment: I really like the jplay...thanks